# Iterate over list and valid email address

Tags: c#

I have the following code:
(emailList type is `List<string>`)

```
//Add All emails
foreach (var mail in emailList)
{
    var isEmail = Regex.IsMatch(mail.Trim(), @"\A(?:[a-z0-9!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+(?:\.[a-z0-9!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+)*@(?:[a-z0-9](?:[a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9])?\.)+[a-z0-9](?:[a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9])?)\Z", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);

    if (isEmail)
    {
        email.BccRecipients.Add(mail.Trim());
        sbInfoLog.Append($"Email: {mail.Trim()}\n");
    }
    else
    {
        sbAlertLog.Append($"Not valid email address: {mail}\n");
    }
}
```

I'm looking for another way to:

1. To validate the email address
2. To Iterate over the list (Maybe with ForEach etc..)

Any suggestions?

Comment: http://www.ex-parrot.com/~pdw/Mail-RFC822-Address.html - tl;dr the only way to properly validate an email address is to send it an email.

Comment: Email addresses have a lot of gotchas, so trying to validate them with a program is troublesome, and trying to validate them with a regex is a nightmare.

Answer (score 14):

This is a method I've used without any problems so far.

```
bool IsValidEmail(string email)
{
    try 
    {
        var addr = new System.Net.Mail.MailAddress(email);
        return true;
    }
    catch 
    {
        return false;
    }
}
```

To check the validity and handle each case you could do this.

```
var emailChecklist = emails.Select(x => 
    new { IsValid = IsValidEmail(x.Trim()), Address = x });

foreach(var email in emailChecklist)
{
    if (email.IsValid)
    {
        email.BccRecipients.Add(email.Address.Trim());
        sbInfoLog.Append($"Email: {email.Address.Trim()}\n");
    }
    else
    {
        sbAlertLog.Append($"Not valid email address: {email.Address}\n");
    }
}
```

I left the trim in the loop because I noticed that you didn't trim on the invalid email log. I assumed that you were trying to preserve the original value.

Comment: +1 better to use the [MailAddress](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/591bk9e8(v=vs.110).aspx) constructor's validation than to try (and usually fail) at validating addresses via regex

Comment: Even better: Use semantically meaningful types throughout the program. Then you can never accidentally confuse an arbitrary string with an e-mail address. It also helps to search the web for email validation regex. Once I did that, I knew that I never want to get into that business.

Comment: +1 for using LINQ and anonymous types, and definitely +1 for using .NET's built-in email class to do the validation! That snippet should be in every self-respecting .NET dev's toolbox.

Comment: For anyone curious (as I was), `MailAddress` uses a much more [RFC-compliant parser](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System/net/System/Net/mail/MailAddressParser.cs,87b2cacf203ba13e) instead of a simple (or complicated) RegEx.  Unfortunately this parser (`MailAddressParser`) is in an internal class so the only way to access it is via the `MailAddress` constructor.

Comment: @Nick Ugh, what a messy parser. I can’t help but feel that [using a properly written regex](https://github.com/mspanc/rfc822/blob/master/lib/rfc822.rb) would have resulted in much more readable code with comparable efficiency.

Comment: @KonradRudolph There is *no* Regex that is RFC compliant and bug-free / can handle all exceptions like comments etc. (see [this comment](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/156448/iterate-over-list-and-valid-email-address#comment296217_156448). The only tried and true way to make sure an emailaddress is 'valid' is by sending it an email with confirmation link. See also [here](http://isemail.info/about) and [here](http://code.iamcal.com/php/rfc822/tests/) for testcases and the mess that emailaddresses are.

Comment: @RobIII The same applies to non-regex textual tests, then (and in particular to the check used in .NET’s `MailAddress`). Furthermore, while non-textual validation has its place, so does textual validation. You don’t want to/can’t always attempt to send emails, and using textual validation can offer reasonable accuracy depending on your use-case. But more importantly, your claim that the regex isn’t RFC compliant is an outlandish claim, and I’d like some evidence for that please.

Comment: Guess it ain't necessary to save var addr after calling the constructor? Or is this a C++ thing to make sure exception is thrown?

Comment: @KonradRudolph `But more importantly, your claim that the regex isn’t RFC compliant is an outlandish claim, and I’d like some evidence for that please.` I was referring to RFC 5321: [What RFC is the authority for mailbox formats? RFC 822? RFC 2822? Nope, it's RFC 5321](http://isemail.info/about). I don't have an environment to test ruby code but did *you* run [all 168 unittests](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/dominicsayers/isemail/master/test/tests.xml) on it?

Comment: @KonradRudolph `and in particular to the check used in .NET’s MailAddress` For the record: I never stated *that* method is correct. Hell, it *also* [fails 106 out of the 168 tests](https://dotnetfiddle.net/0Aaa88)...

Comment: @RobIII Right, then we actually agree: I *also* don’t think that a textual test for email address validity makes sense except in limited scenarios, and in those I’d probably use something along the lines of `/@/`. But *if* you’re writing a parser, don’t fall into the pitfall of avoiding regex (unless it’s because you’re using parser combinators!) and for all that’s holy don’t write a parser by manipulating character indices manually.

Comment: @KonradRudolph `Right, then we essentially agree` I guess we do 

Comment: Correction on [my earlier statement](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/156448/iterate-over-list-and-valid-email-address/156464?noredirect=1#comment296325_156464): '*it [the MailAddress method] also fails 106 out of the 168 tests*': it "only" fails [38 cases](https://dotnetfiddle.net/0Aaa88) depending on how 'lax' you want to interpret the RFC's / allow deprecated things etc.

Comment: @KonradRudolph I don't disagree that the `MailAddressParser` is lacking, however the vast majority of regular expressions are going to be just as bad, or worse.  That said, validating email addresses is a fascinating case of the 80/20 rule (or in this case, probably more like 98/2) and technically vs practically correct.  I'd prefer a library solution (hence advocating `MailAddress`) but if I had to roll my own then I'd probably just use RegEx.

Comment: @Nick But I’m explicitly not talking about “the vast majority” of regex (I know [Sturgeon’s law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sturgeon's_law), after all). I’m talking about a competent solution. And that easily beats a competent hand-written parser.

Comment: -1 for validating with `try/catch` where it can be avoided.

Comment: @t3chb0t Are you saying that this method could avoid try/catch, or that another method should be used? I'm still learning so I'm curious what problems this method has with the try/catch.

Answer (score 3):

You can use the `ToLookup` extension to group the emails by validation result. To access the collection you use either `true` or `false`. With this approach you can split the invalid/valid email handling.

You also should put the very long pattern in a constant.

```
var emails = new[] { "..", ".." };

const string EmailPattern = "..";

var validEmails = emails
    .Select(x => x.Trim())
    .ToLookup(x => Regex.IsMatch(x, EmailPattern, RegexOptions.IgnoreCase));

foreach (var email in validEmails[true])
{
    // ...
}

// do something else with validEmails[false]
```

Answer (score 3):

I forget the syntax but regex is run time processed so define the regex outside the loop and call it inside the loop.  If you notice the compiler will not pick up regex syntax errors.  You don't get them until run time.  It is significant.  When I tested creating the Regex run time took longer than processing.

I would just trim up front

```
mail = mail.Trim();
```

And I would break out the pattern in a separate string so if you change it you are touching less.

```
public static void ValidateEmail()
{
    List<string> emailList = new List<string>() { "emailList@se.com", "Not Valid Email"  };
    List<string> emailListGood = new List<string>();
    StringBuilder sbAlertLog = new StringBuilder();
    string pattern = @"\A(?:[a-z0-9!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+(?:\.[a-z0-9!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+)*@(?:[a-z0-9](?:[a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9])?\.)+[a-z0-9](?:[a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9])?)\Z";
    Regex regex = new Regex(pattern, RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
    string mailTrim;
    foreach (var mail in emailList)
    {
        mailTrim = mail.Trim();
        if (regex.IsMatch(mailTrim))
        {
            emailListGood.Add(mailTrim);
        }
        else
        {
            sbAlertLog.Append($"Not valid email address: {mailTrim}\n");
        }
    }
}
```